# React.js - AsyncStorage: Have to press button twice to save the correct value i want

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage, savestate

I am trying to create a button that when i click it it will be disabled and when i reload the app it will stay disabled , until i press clear.

The problem is i have to click twice to get the result i want. Here is my code:

```
 github.com/giannischiout/stateBtn/tree/master
```

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Button,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';

import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

export const BtnSave = () => {
    const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => { getButtonOption() }, [])


      const getButtonOption = async () => {
        try {
          const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('buttonCheck', )
          const value = JSON.parse(jsonValue)
            setIsChecked(value);
        } catch(e) {
          console.log(e)
        }
      }

      //Execute when i click the button
      const buttonActions = async () => {
        
        setIsChecked(previousValue => !previousValue)
        buttonSaveClicked();
      };

      const buttonSaveClicked = async () => {
        let btnValue = isChecked.toString();
        //Have to click twice to change the value 
        console.log(`btn value is: ${btnValue}`)
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('buttonCheck',btnValue )
      };
    
    return  (
        <TouchableOpacity  >

      <View>
        <Button  title='save settings' onPress={buttonActions}></Button>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>

    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the getButtonOption function, since the key does not exist yet in the asyncstorage, it returns a null. Hence your isChecked is null on the first press. A very simple fix is to check if the value that is being retrieved on first load is a null value or not. Then set the correct state from there.

```
  const getButtonOption = async () => {
    try {
      const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('buttonCheck');
      const value = JSON.parse(jsonValue);
      value ? setIsChecked(value) : setIsChecked(false);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I totally understood your question but I can see some improvements that could help you and maybe it'll solve what you want.

#### Not parsing correctly the received JSON

I noticed that your function from parsing isn't considering the value as `Boolean` and you are trying to set a string `'true'` or `'false'` (string) to the value `isChecked`, that you expect to be `true` or `false` (booleans).

Remember that if you expect a boolean value and pass a non-empty string to it, it'll always evaluate `true`!

A simple change could fix that when saving:

```js
// saving
AsyncStorage.setItem("buttonCheck", isChecked ? "true" : "false")
// loading
const jsonValue = AsyncStorage.setItem("buttonCheck")
const { buttonCheck } = JSON.parse(jsonValue);
seIsChecked(buttonCheck === "true")
```

#### No `await`ing inside your `buttonActions()` function

I also noticed that you forgot to `await` the response from `buttonSaveClicked()` inside your `buttonActions()` function. I think changing the value from `AsyncStorage` inside this callback is a bad practice and provided one approach that I consider better later at this same response.

#### Calling an `async` function inside `useEffect()` from outside context

If you want to call an `async` function inside a `useEffect()` callback, make that function inside of the `useEffect()` callback such as ([this article has some context about it](https://devtrium.com/posts/async-functions-useeffect#write-the-asynchronous-function-inside-the-useeffect)):

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const getButtonOption = async () => {
    try {
      const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('buttonCheck');
      const { buttonCheck } = JSON.parse(jsonValue);
      setIsChecked(buttonCheck === "true");
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  getButtonOption();
}, [])
```

#### Reactively calling `AsyncStorage.setItem()` inside another `useEffect()`

You could take advantage of the reactive behavior of ReactJS and change the AsyncStorage value when the local state is changed, inside another `useEffect()` hook directly. Something like this could work:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const saveToAsyncStorage = async () => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('buttonCheck', isChecked ? "true" : "false");
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  saveToAsyncStorage();
}, [isChecked]);
```

I hope this could help you to solve your code!

Comment: I basically want to create a button, with an initial state of 'false', when the state is 'true', i want to disable the button and save that state. When i reload the application, i want the button to be disabled. So getItem should fetch 'true' and set the button to disabled on reload. 

cant seem to figure it out, even with your solution

Comment: You passed the default value to the `isChecked` at the `useState()` hook as `false`, so it'll always start at `false` and then it'll load from the AsyncStorage and change the value. I still think that the function inside the `useEffect()` callback solve your problem. As a side solution, you could try to create a loading state to only render the component after the AsyncStorage is fully loaded and it'll prevent rendering before it.

Comment: Also, if possible, could you provide a working repo to give more context? You could upload your code to a github repo and paste the link here.

Comment: this is what i have done so far
https://github.com/giannischiout/stateBtn/tree/master
it works only if i press the button twice, then it changes the value.
If then i add disabled ={isChecked} it stays disabled after refresh